# How to call a stored procedure using while loop in mysql

Tags: mysql

My question may sound lame but still I cant get whats wrong with this code. I have made a stored procedure in sqlyog and now I want to call it. I have tried almost everything but it doesn't work.

```
 SET @x=1;
 WHILE @x<=10 DO
 CALL mypro();
 SET @x=@x+1;
 END WHILE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a function or stored procedure? The `WHILE` needs to be executed in that context.

Comment: No i'm just writing it in the query area where the queries are written

Comment: If I simply write CALL mypro() it works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flow control statements like `IF, WHILE` need to be executed in context of a function or stored procedure. If you wish to execute `mypro()` in a loop, that action itself must be created as a procedure.  Below I will create a procedure called `call_mypro_x10()` which calls your original stored procedure in a `WHILE` loop.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE call_mypro_x10()
BEGIN
  SET @x = 1;
  WHILE @x <= 10 DO
    CALL mypro();
    SET @x := @x + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call this procedure which wraps the other one:

```
CALL call_mypro_x10();
```

Note that the `DELIMITER` statements may not be necessary in all clients, and some MySQL clients supply a different method of specifying an alternate delimiter needed in stored procedure and function definitions. Apparently [SQLyog supports `DELIMITER`](http://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/Delimiter_in_SQLyog_MySQL_Client.htm)

There is [an open feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48777) to permit flow control statements as part of normal query execution.

Comment: Thankyou but I dont have enough reputation points to do that whereas I have already clicked on the tick